# Do connectors with mounting tabs like this need to be grounded?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, connector, components

The connector I have attached has these solder tabs on the side (red arrow). I think it's fairly common. The question is, when creating components for something like this, should I add two additional pins in the connector symbol for this? And if I should, should these be grounded in the design?

[image]

Comment: I would not do that. Someone could think it is 6 pin connector, when he looks at your circuit diagram. Their role is purely mechanical robustness.

Comment: 7 pin, not 6 pin

Comment: @esehic I could label them as MNT1 and MNT2 in the component? Like something you'd do for USB?